# SQL using Floor to round down

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and trying to use the Floor function to round down but I'm getting a message saying that the function required 1 argument. I'm not seeing the issue and it's probably something very simple i'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
,(Floor( 
        CASE 
            WHEN ret2 <> 0 OR originalretail <> 0 
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN ret2 > 0 
                            THEN (ret2-retone)/ret2 
                        WHEN originalretail > 0 
                            THEN (originalretail-retone)/originalretail 
                        ELSE NULL 
                      END 
        END 
        ,2) * 100 AS [Savings %]
```

Comment: Your code does not use the `floor()` function, it uses the `round()` function.

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging the right piece of code?

Comment: sorry I was originally using Round which worked but if I swap in the Floor function i get the error. I've fixed the code to show floor.

Comment: Well perhaps if you showed the code that doesn't work instead of the code that does this would have been clear. You have to specify the precision in ROUND with the second parameter. Floor receives only one parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I swapped Round for Floor because that works but if I switch Round for
>   Floor function I get the error. I'll update the code

Because floor takes 1 argument and you are passing 2 in, the nested case and the numeric 2. You also have a rogue open parentheses at the beginning...

```
,(round(
        --First Argument  
        CASE 
            WHEN ret2 <> 0 OR originalretail <> 0 
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN ret2 > 0 
                            THEN (ret2-retone)/ret2 
                        WHEN originalretail > 0 
                            THEN (originalretail-retone)/originalretail 
                        ELSE NULL 
                      END 
        END
        --second...
        ,2) * 100 AS [Savings %]
```

To fix that, remove the comma and 2 and leading parentheses.

```
,floor( 
        CASE 
            WHEN ret2 <> 0 OR originalretail <> 0 
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN ret2 > 0 
                            THEN (ret2-retone)/ret2 
                        WHEN originalretail > 0 
                            THEN (originalretail-retone)/originalretail 
                        ELSE NULL 
                      END 
        END 
        ) * 100 AS [Savings %]
```

Also, if your columns are integers, you're going to get integer division.